# Getting city GIS data

Tags: data

I need some help on how to go about it. I do not have much knowledge about GIS.

For a project we need a complete set of city data to perform calculations on.

In terms of generating a map of the city, is there a way that I can get the details of the city - i.e. all streets, landmarks, lanes etc. etc. in any format? Once I have these data, then I can insert them into the database and proceed.

Comment: Try Googling "gis data <city name>".

Comment: Lots of city and county governments make their GIS data publicly available. Some have websites, some don't. I've had good luck with just calling up and asking. Public data is, well, public, but they can charge you a reasonable fee for the actual cost of providing it to you.

Comment: Which city are we talking about?

Comment: At first, India

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would highly recommend the [OpenStreetMap](http://openstreetmap.org) data. Much of the world is represented, with everything from roads to parks.

[Cloudmade](http://downloads.cloudmade.com) offers Shapefiles, but I prefer the .osm format data you can get many places because it contains more information.

In the US, [TIGER/Line](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/) is also an option.

Comment: Thanks. I knew about OpenStreetMap but was just searching for more options